# My count vectorizer codes ran perfectly flags ''utf8' error with no structural change

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, nltk, stop-words

My CountVectorizer codes that ran perfectly suddenly gave me 'utf8' error the next minute I reran it. I have attached my codes and the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tfidfvectorizer.py", line 32, in <module>
    word_count_vector=vectorizer.fit_transform(lines)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 1031, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 943, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 329, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 141, in decode
    doc = doc.decode(self.encoding, self.decode_error)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 305: invalid start byte
```

as3:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages# cat sitecustomize.py

```
# encoding=utf8  
import sys  

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

import re
import sys
import os
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

#import sys
#reload(sys)
#sys.setdefaultencoding("ISO-8859-1")

#a.encode('utf-8').strip()

os.chdir("/Users/lucy/Desktop/down1")

file=[]

for files in os.listdir("/Users/lucy/Desktop/down1"):
    with open(files) as f: 
        #files.encode('utf-8').strip()
        lineList = f.readlines()
        lines=b" ".join(lineList) 
    lines=[lines] 
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
    #[texts]=yes
    word_count_vector=vectorizer.fit_transform(lines)
    #with open(os.path.join(root,files),"r") as auto:
    file.append(word_count_vector)
    #print(file)


print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
```

Comment: Your input files are not encoded with UTF-8, but you are trying to decode them with UTF-8 (which is some default, apparently). How did you create/obtain the files in *Desktop/down1/*?

Comment: They are parsed file which contain the MD&A SECTION OF THE 10-K

Comment: Ok, I don't know what that means, but this is why I asked: if you created the files, make sure you use UTF-8 for saving them. If you got them from somewhere, they should tell you what encoding it's in, then use this for reading instead of UTF-8.

Comment: ... and I just saw that you're using the `sys.setdefaultencoding` hack. Don't do that. I know it's been really popular on Stack Overflow in the Python-2 days, but there are good reasons why it's not recommended. Instead, explicitly declare the codec when opening files for reading/writing, eg. with `io.open(path, encoding='utf8')` from the `io` module.